# Razor Page Handler with Class as Arg

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

How can I create a handler that takes in a class as an arg.  This is based of the [mediatr example for Razor pages](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/blob/1f1073f867a3b3e7fa25bb1dab0006fa8a72239f/ContosoUniversity/Pages/Instructors/CreateEdit.cshtml.cs#L37). In the example, the 'Query' object has only an 'Id' property.  I want to have 2 properties, for example:

```
public async Task OnGetEditAsync(Query query)
{
    Data = await _mediator.Send(query);
}

public class Query
{
    public string FirstId { get; set; }
    public string SecondId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a route like this in my cshtml:

```
<a asp-page="/TestPage" asp-route-FirstId="abc" asp-route-SecondId="123">Test Link</a>
```

I get a 400 error.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Well, `abc` is not a valid GUID, and neither is `123`.

Comment: Your right, my code uses valid guid, I just didn't feel like writing them out... I changed the example to be strings

Comment: Please do **not** edit your question after someone takes the time to answer. It makes it look like the answerer was not paying attention or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link is pointing to wrong handler, You have OnGet*Edit*Async where *Edit* is name of handler; try this:

```
<a asp-page="TestPage" asp-page-handler="Edit" asp-route-FirstId="abc" asp-route-SecondId="123">Test Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@{
var test= new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "FirstId ", "something" },
                { "SecondId ", "something else" }
            };
}

<a asp-page="/TestPage"
   asp-all-route-data="test">Test Link</a>
```

Will generate the `<a href="/TestPage?FirstId=something&SecondId=something else">Test Link</a>`